# Show that when adding an edge to a path $P$ of length D, the diameter of the resulting $P'$ is at least $\frac{D}{2}$

Tags: graph-theory

My attempt so far: The length of a path $P_n$ with n Vertices is $n-1$ (number of edges) therefore $P$ has $D+1$ Vertices. The diameter of a path is the length of the longest distance between two vertices, therefore the diameter of $P$ is equal to its length = $D$.

When we now add an extra edge between two vertices, we probably have to split the proof into a path with an even amount of vertices and one with an uneven amount of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Let the vertices along the path be $u ... v ... w ...x ...y$ where the points $v,x$ are to be joined by the extra edge and where $w$ is as close as possible to the midpoint of $vx$.

Let the initial distances $d(uv),d(vw),d(wx),d(xy)$ be $j,k,l,m$ respectively. Then
$$j+k+l+m=D.$$
Note also that $|k-l|\le 1$.

After adding the extra edge, $d(uw)= j+k$ and $(dwy)=l+m$. Therefore $$d(uw)+(dwy)=D$$ and so one of these distances must be at least $\frac{D}{2}$.